# pullback and fiber sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $A\rightarrow D\leftarrow C$ a diagram of connected pointed toplogical space where $A\rightarrow D$ is a fibration. Denote $P=A\times_{D}C$.  We obtain a homotopy fiber sequence $$ \Omega D\rightarrow P\rightarrow A\times C $$

If we suppose that $D=\Omega X$ for some pointed topological space $X$. Do we obtain a homotopy fiber sequence $$ P\rightarrow A\times C\rightarrow D ?$$
where the map $A\times C\rightarrow D$ is obtained as a composition $A\times C\rightarrow D\times D\rightarrow D$ (the second map is a concatenation of loops)

Comment: The hofiber of $A\times C\to D$ has a model consisting of points $(a,c)$ together with a homotopy $f(a)g(c)^{-1} \sim *$, so points $(a,c)$ together with a homotopy $f(a)\sim g(c)$, so it amounts to a point in a model of the homotopy pullback $A\times^h_D C$, but $P$ is precisely that homotopy pullback, because $A\to D$ is a fibration.

Comment: @Max if i understand correctly your comment then the answer is YES ?

Comment: This is true if one of the loops is inverted before the concatenation in the definition of the map $D \times D \to D$ and the chosen point of $D$ is the trivial loop.

Comment: @ValeryIsaev Now I see thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Here are some details.

1. The space $P$ sits in  homotopy pullback diagram
   $\require{AMScd}$
   $$
   \begin{CD}
   P @>>> D \\
   @VVV@VVV \\
   A\times C @>>> D\times D
   \end{CD}
   $$
   where the the right vertical map is the diagonal. In fact, one can see this by replacing the latter map with the free path fibration $D^I \to D\times D$. After this replacement the diagram becomes a pullback and a pullback with one of the terminal maps a fibration is always a homotopy pullback.
2. When $D = \Omega X$, there the diagonal is **induced** by the map $m:D\times D \to D$ given by $(\gamma_1,\gamma_2) \mapsto \gamma_1 \cdot \bar\gamma_2$, where the bar means loop inversion.  This means that there is a commutative homotopy pullback
   $$
   \begin{CD}
   D @>\text{diag} >> D\times D \\
   @VVV @VV m V \\
   * @>>> D
   \end{CD}
   $$
   where $*$ is some contractible space. (Perhaps the easiest way to see this is to note that the diagonal $X\to X \times X$ has homotopy fiber $D$.)
3. The base change of a map which is induced in also induced: this means that there is a commutative homotopy pullback
   $$
   \begin{CD}
   P @>>> A \times C \\
   @VVV @VVV \\
   * @>>> D
   \end{CD}
   $$
   where the bottom map is the same as in the previous diagram.